# Contact Form is not working. IntegrityError at /contact/

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Models.py

```
class ContactForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        ContactForm.objects.create(
            name = name,
            subject = subject,
            email = email,
            message = message
        )
        return render(
            request,
            'blog/contact.html',
            {
                'msg':'Details have been saved. We will get back to you.'
            }
        )
    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/contact.html')
```

contact.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container wrap mb-5" style="margin-top: 100px">
        <h2 class="text">Contact Us</h2>
        <form action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" name="name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" name="email">
            <input type="message" placeholder="Write Your Message" name="msg">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" name="Submit">
        </form>
        {% if msg %}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ msg }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93ZsA.png) error occured while I click on the submit button.

It shows `IntegrityError at /contact/ NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_contacts.message.`

Comment: Your question was marked as "requires editing" by a reviewer. Accordingly I improved the question formatting during a successing review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that in the html, for the message input, the name tag is 'msg' and in view it is request.POST.get('message'). Hence it cannot find that post variable. Also there is no such input type as 'message', So you can change that too,
 The code for the line now looks like

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Write Your Message" name="message">
```

Also getting straight post objects is not recommended, it leaves you open to security holes. You should use Django forms to clean data before using user input. Check out the official documentation for more help
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/